# Syntax not understood value.match

Tags: javascript, string, syntax, match

in a javascript I noticed this thing that I did not understand how it works:

```
function validate_pin(frm)
{
    var piN = document.getElementById('codice');
    if (!piN) {
        var piN = document.getElementById('invio');
    }

    if (!piN.value.match(/^\d{3}$/) && !piN.value.match(/^\d{4}$/)) {
        // SORRY! WRONG PIN!
        //alert('ATTENZIONE! INSERIRE UN PIN NUMERICO!');
        alert('Attenzione! Codice PIN errato!');
        piN.focus();

        return false;
    }
}
```

and the string `if (!piN.value.match(/^\d{3}$/) && !piN.value.match(/^\d{4}$/))` what it means?

Comment: Did you search for [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)?

Answer (score 1):

`pin` is a DOM element, most likely an [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

`pin.value` is the value of the input element, which is a string.

[`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) matches a string against a regular expression (a [RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)), returning a falsy value when no matches are found.

I'm also assuming that you may not know what that regex does, so explanation:

- The `^` anchor matches at start of string and `$` matches at the end.
- `\d` is a character class `[0-9]` that needs to be matched exactly `3` times (in the first test) or `4` times (2nd test).

Therefore your string must consist of, from start to end, exactly 3 or 4 digit characters.

---

Side-note: your code would be more optimal written this way:

```
if (!/^\d{3,4}$/.test(piN.value)) {}
```

`regexp.test` only returns a boolean indicating whether the string matches the pattern or not, while `string.match` will return an array of matches on success (coerces to `true`) or `null` when no matches are found (coerces to `false`).

Hence both have the same outcome, but `test` is more suitable for regular pattern testing.

---

Yet another alternative, without relying on regex:

```
var pinValue = parseInt(pin.value, 10);
if (pinValue >= 100 && pinValue <= 9999) {}
```

Only difference from the previous regex versions is that [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) will ignore leading and trailing whitespace as well as trailing invalid chars (which should be corner cases). This option is more readable IMO. You can choose which solution suits your use case better.

Comment: @Bergi Actually I just thought about something even better, but thanks! `=]`

Answer (score 0):

That's a regular expression:) You check if the pin is 3 or 4 digits long.
You can learn more about regex [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation:

```
function validate_pin(frm)
{
    // Get an input element with ID=codice
    var piN = document.getElementById('codice');

    // If there is no such element, get input with ID=invio
    if (!piN) {
        var piN = document.getElementById('invio');
    }

    // If value of this input is NOT a 3- or 4-digit number, alert with an error
    // and return false.
    if (!piN.value.match(/^\d{3}$/) && !piN.value.match(/^\d{4}$/)) {
        // SORRY! WRONG PIN!
        //alert('ATTENZIONE! INSERIRE UN PIN NUMERICO!');
        alert('Attenzione! Codice PIN errato!');
        piN.focus();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Regular expression `/^\d{3}$/` means: "String which has three digits (`\d`) and nothing else (because of `^` at the beggining and `$` at the end".

For example:

- `/^\d{3}$/` matches: `123`, but does not match `a123` or `123a`.
- `/\d{3}$/` matches: `123` and `a123`, but does not match `123a`.
- `/^\d{3}/` matches: `123` and `123a`, but does not match `a123`.

The condition: `if (!piN.value.match(/^\d{3}$/) && !piN.value.match(/^\d{4}$/))` could be written in a shorter form: `if (!pIN.value.match(/^\d{3,4}$/))`.

Comment: @user2723065 - yes, any number. So for `\d{3}` this means 000-999 and for `\d{4}` - 0000-9999.